# How to use combination Select Query and update query?

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have used Mysql and I input column that is wrong.

So I have to modify all of columns:

[image]

As picture above I want to re-insert query that After the calculation by reading am_high1, am_high2.

Clearly, if am_high1 value euql 0.037, am_high1 value = 0.037/0.796 (re-insert)

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: So...you want to select all records where am_high1 is 0.037 and update it to 0.037/0.796?

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: @zedfoxus it is right your understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write a query like this:

```
update <tablename>
set am_high1 = am_high1/0.796
where am_high1 = 0.037;
```

That should do it for you. Before you run the query, make sure you back the data up so that if that's not what you really want, you have a backup to restore from.